How to use get aria-label using BeautifulSoup scraping in python
I have a large number of div class in my HTML. Each div classes contains an H3 class, which contains a div aria-label whose text I want to scrape in my Python file. I've been able to create a list of the outer divs, but I'm not sure how to locate and use the aria-label inside each one.
Below is my code so far, and attached is a picture of the html file:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

url = "https://artsci.calendar.utoronto.ca/search-courses?page=0"
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

courses = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'views-row'})

course_titles = []

for item in courses:
    # locate and add item's aria-label to the course_titles list

html reference to show div/h3/aria-label structure

You can use CSS selectors and the select or select_one methods of bs4:
labels = [d.get('aria-label') for d in soup.select('div.views-row > h3 > div')]

